# How to make a Shell to be always on top in SWT?

Tags: java, windows, macos, swt, always-on-top

I'd like to implement "Always on top" configuration option in my application that takes effect immediately.

I know that I can call `Shell` constructor with `ON_TOP` style. Is there a way to do that at runtime, that is after a `Shell` instance has already been created?

Answer (score 3):

In Cocoa you need to use reflection to get at the Shell instance variable `window` and then call `window.setLevel(OS.NSStatusWindowLevel)`.

In Carbon you need to get at the `shellHandle` instance variable and then call `OS.SetWindowGroup(shellHandle, OS.kFloatingWindowClass)`. You might be able to get away with doing just that much, depending on your needs.

In either case, you should also forcibly add the `SWT.ON_TOP` bit to the `style` field. Particularly in Carbon, lots of things rely on that bit being set.

Comment: this sounds very promising, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 3):

On windows, you can do it like this:

```
private static final void toggleAlwaysOnTop(Shell shell, boolean isOnTop){
    long handle = shell.handle;
    Point location = shell.getLocation();
    Point dimension = shell.getSize();
    OS.SetWindowPos(handle, isOnTop ? OS.HWND_TOPMOST : OS.HWND_NOTOPMOST,location.x, location.y, dimension.x, dimension.y, 0);
}
```

All those api's are public so there is no need for reflection.

The last argument for `SetWindowPos` is not the same with `Shell.getStyle()`. Leaving it as 0 currently causing no problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

One time I had similar problem and I had found such thread:

http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg11143.html

Unfortunately I don't remember if it works...

Comment: Thanks, Lukasz. I'll try that and see if it works. I'll still need a solution for Mac though. I'll see if I can find anything from SWT source code as Aaron suggested.

Comment: It looks like the page is moved to http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/323132/ . However the code does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to change the styles of widgets after they have been created.

You must check which code gets executed during creation time and then call the specific native method (in the class `OS`).

Download the source for SWT for your platform to see how it works. It's not magic, just a bit of manual debugging.